# Problem in Data Validation in Google Sheets API Batch Update

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api, dropdown, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to update a Google Sheet using sheets API batchUpdate function. What I want to do is to add data validation (drop-downs) to certain columns in my sheet. I'm sending a list of requests where each request has the parameters needed for each drop-down. However, as I'm adding requests to the list, the conditions in all the previously added requests get replaced with the new condition.

My method is as follows:

```
public BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse setDropdownForPriceTest(String spreadsheetId) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    Sheets service = GoogleDriveConnection.getSheetsService();
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ConditionValue> conditionValueList = new ArrayList<>();
    BooleanCondition booleanCondition;
    DataValidationRule dataValidationRule;
    GridRange range;

    conditionValueList.clear();
    String[] tripType = PriceBatchTestCase.TRIPTYPE;
    for (String str: tripType) {
        conditionValueList.add(new ConditionValue().setUserEnteredValue(str));
    }
    booleanCondition = new BooleanCondition().setType("ONE_OF_LIST").setValues(conditionValueList);
    dataValidationRule = new DataValidationRule().setCondition(booleanCondition).setShowCustomUi(true).setStrict(true);
    range = new GridRange().setSheetId(0).setStartRowIndex(1).setStartColumnIndex(1).setEndColumnIndex(2);
    requests.add(new Request().setSetDataValidation(new SetDataValidationRequest().setRule(dataValidationRule).setRange(range)));

    conditionValueList.clear();
    String[] policyType = policyPackageService.getArrayPolicyPackageCode();
    for (String str: policyType) {
        conditionValueList.add(new ConditionValue().setUserEnteredValue(str));
    }
    booleanCondition = new BooleanCondition().setType("ONE_OF_LIST").setValues(conditionValueList);
    dataValidationRule = new DataValidationRule().setCondition(booleanCondition).setShowCustomUi(true).setStrict(true);
    range = new GridRange().setSheetId(0).setStartRowIndex(1).setStartColumnIndex(2).setEndColumnIndex(3);
    requests.add(new Request().setSetDataValidation(new SetDataValidationRequest().setRule(dataValidationRule).setRange(range)));

    conditionValueList.clear();
    String[] area = PriceBatchTestCase.AREA;
    for (String str: area) {
        conditionValueList.add(new ConditionValue().setUserEnteredValue(str));
    }
    booleanCondition = new BooleanCondition().setType("ONE_OF_LIST").setValues(conditionValueList);
    dataValidationRule = new DataValidationRule().setCondition(booleanCondition).setShowCustomUi(true).setStrict(true);
    range = new GridRange().setSheetId(0).setStartRowIndex(1).setStartColumnIndex(15).setEndColumnIndex(16);
    requests.add(new Request().setSetDataValidation(new SetDataValidationRequest().setRule(dataValidationRule).setRange(range)));

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
    return response;
}
```

Here's what the list of requests should look like (converted to JSON) before executing:

```
[
  {
    "setDataValidation": {
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 2,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startColumnIndex": 1,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      },
      "rule": {
        "condition": {
          "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
          "values": [
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "SINGLE_TRIP"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "ANNUAL_MULTI_TRIP"
            }
          ]
        },
        "showCustomUi": true,
        "strict": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "setDataValidation": {
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 3,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startColumnIndex": 2,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      },
      "rule": {
        "condition": {
          "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
          "values": [
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "ESSENTIALS"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "CLASSIC"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "DELUXE"
            }
          ]
        },
        "showCustomUi": true,
        "strict": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "setDataValidation": {
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 16,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startColumnIndex": 15,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      },
      "rule": {
        "condition": {
          "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
          "values": [
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_LR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_LR"
            }
          ]
        },
        "showCustomUi": true,
        "strict": true
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Even though the individual requests are constructed correctly, the actual list of requests look like this:

```
[
  {
    "setDataValidation": {
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 2,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startColumnIndex": 1,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      },
      "rule": {
        "condition": {
          "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
          "values": [
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_LR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_LR"
            }
          ]
        },
        "showCustomUi": true,
        "strict": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "setDataValidation": {
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 3,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startColumnIndex": 2,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      },
      "rule": {
        "condition": {
          "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
          "values": [
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_LR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_LR"
            }
          ]
        },
        "showCustomUi": true,
        "strict": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "setDataValidation": {
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 16,
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startColumnIndex": 15,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      },
      "rule": {
        "condition": {
          "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
          "values": [
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_LR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "EUROPE_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_HR"
            },
            {
              "userEnteredValue": "WORLD_LR"
            }
          ]
        },
        "showCustomUi": true,
        "strict": true
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So that all three drop-downs have the same values. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason for this while writing some other code. The problem has been quite simple.
In my method I'm using the same list `conditionValueList` for each of my conditions, clearing it and filling values again each time. As the value of the reference to that list gets passed each time, the lists of `ConditionValue` items previously set into the `booleanCondition` variable also get changed accordingly. Hence all the `ConditionValue` lists in `booleanCondition` have the same value (the last assigned value) by the end.